# LiveTemplate for TODO shortcut seems not working

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using `Intellij Ultimate 2023.3.6` and LiveTemplate to add TODO with words "todo" not working anymore.

I tried to clear cache, restart, disable and re-enable live template but nothing seems working.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

I'm talking about this, in past versions of intellij works as expected:
[image]